# Primefaces (5.3) - How to set mimetype on "type field" of window save

Tags: jsf, primefaces, download, stream, mime-types

I am using **fileDownload** of Primefaces - version 5.3 - with **DefaultStreamedContent**
On controller, I put the mimetype like "image/png", but when open the window to download, the type doesn't appear.
Can I set it on window save according image? It´s possible?
Thanks ever so much!!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQH9p.png)

Comment: This situation is occurring with Firefox

Comment: My problem was the browser. I uninstalled and installed again. Now it works